# "Set the tone" I learn a lot, I enjoy my class

Tags: grammar, present-tense, sequence-of-tenses, future-time, future-constructions

I received some instructions which I believe sound a bit strange but I can't find the exact arguments to prove myself wrong or right.

The slide is called: SET UP THE TONE. Afterwards, I have to ask students to read out loud the following sentences:

> Today is a beautiful day.
> I learn a lot.
> I enjoy my class.

I believe it should be

> I will learn a lot.
> I will enjoy my class.

Some people tell me it is correct the way it is if the intention is to speak in present tense. Isn't setting up the tone preparing for the future? To me "I learn a lot" would be correct if there were more words before or after it...

> I enjoy my class when I'm well rested.
> I learn a lot through this program.

What do you guys think? Help. Thanks

Comment: That is probably true, but what is the *intention* of the lesson and the level of the students? A basic class might just be asked to say simple sentences, and the 2nd and 3rd might not be conversational consequences of "Today is a beautiful day." The 4th and 5th sentences are not in the present tense.

Comment: Is it 'set the tone' (title) or 'set up the tone' (question)?

Comment: have you looked up [set the tone](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set%20the%20tone) in a dictionary? It doesn't necessarily relate to the future, but to early things. So saying what you've done in the past or are doing in the present would be setting the tone.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to say.  Both are "correct".

> I learn a lot.   (Everyday, this is a general fact about me and my learning)

> I will learn a lot (A promise or prediction about the future.  In context it would mean "I will learn a lot in this lesson".   Perhaps I didn't learn a lot yesterday, but today I promise to try hard.)

I'm not completely convinced of the point of doing this.  Probably you want to modify their behaviour and become better learners.  That being so, it doesn't matter a jot if the grammar is right, the only thing that matters is do the students try harder when they say these words at the start of each lesson?